# How to generate video screencaps of video files via linux commandline

Tags: linux, video, ubuntu, wmv

Is there a command line program for linux (ubuntu) which can generate a large image containing say 6 caps from a given video (e.g. WMV) laid out storyboard style (I know on Windows media player classic can do this)? I need this for part of a script I am writing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I pulled the answer from this site: http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2008/03/29/creating-video-thumbnails-using-ffmpeg/

`ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4 -i test.avi -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 test.jpg`

Where -4 is the number of seconds into the file to grab the screenshot, 320x240 is the screenshot size, and test.jpg is the output file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use [SlickSlice](http://slickslice.sourceforge.net/)

```
./slickslice.sh -x video.avi -s 5x3 -e
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used MPlayer to save frames as images and ImageMagick to combine them:

```
mplayer -nosound -sstep 15 -vo png video.mkv
montage *.png -tile 3x3 -geometry 300x+0+0 screencaps.png
```

Answer (score 1):

[vcsi](https://github.com/amietn/vcsi) can do this. It is a command-line tool written in Python. Example:

```
vcsi video.mkv -o output.jpg
```